# Getting a NULL response from service.files().list().execute() call to Google Drive from Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I’ve been trying to get a listing of files on `Google Drive` using Python.

The connection is going through, but I am getting a `NULL` response from the `service.files().list().execute()` call.

The Google Drive Folder definitely has files in it.

Here is my code:

```
# Function to list PDF files from Google Drive folder
def get_pdf_files_from_google_drive(folder_id, from_dt, to_dt):
    try:

        SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, SCOPES)

        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        print(service.about().get(fields='user').execute())
        nextPageToken = None
        results = service.files().list(
                                    q="'{0}' in parents".format(folder_id),
                                    pageToken=nextPageToken,
                                    pageSize=5,
                                    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime)",
                                ).execute()
        items = results.get("files", [])
        nextPageToken = results.get("nextPageToken")

        # to iterate through nextPageToken here...

        return items
    except Exception as error:
        print("Got an exception:",error)
```

The

```
print(service.about().get(fields='user').execute())
```

statement gives the following output:

```
{'user': {'kind': 'drive#user', 'displayName': 'xxx@xxx-1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'photoLink': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=YYY', 'me': True, 'permissionId': '123', 'emailAddress': 'xxx@xxx-1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com'}}
```

which would indicate that the connection is going through.

I am new to Python programming, any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution turned out to be quite silly. I had to share the Google drive folder with the service account.
Here is the working code for reference:

```
def get_pdf_files_from_google_drive(folder_id):
    try:

        SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, SCOPES)

        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        print(service.about().get(fields='user').execute())
        nextPageToken = None
        items = []
        while True:
            results = service.files().list(
                q="'{0}' in parents".format(folder_id),
                pageToken=nextPageToken,
                pageSize=5,
                fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime)",
            ).execute()
            items.extend(results.get("files", []))
            nextPageToken = results.get("nextPageToken")
            if nextPageToken is None:
                break
        return items
    except Exception as error:
        print("Got an exception:",error)
```